# SqlLite query a range based on column value

Tags: sqlite, air, sql-like

I have a project in SQLite which contains a table

Prefix table

```
prefix  id
T6A-T6Z 1
YAA-YAZ 2
ZAA-ZAZ 3
7RA-7RZ 4
7TA-7YZ 5
```

For example I have the value “T6C”  which falls in the range of the first record. I need the id of that record. I look into REGEXP as a possible solution but what I read I need a callback function This app is being developed in Adobe Air and I could not find a way to implement the callback.
I also tried the wildcard '_' approach but came up short on that.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lousy data format.  You should really have the beginning and ending values in separate fields.  Oh well.  You can do this with string manipulations:

```
select *
from prefix
where 'T6C' between substr(prefix, 1, 3) and substr(prefix, -3, 3)
```

Comment: Ho, I agree but this is what I was given to work with. however I could manipulate it so I have  two columns. I'll  give this a try first then I think I''ll split the columns as you suggest.

Comment: @Mike . . . Any particular reason that you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: sorry so how I unclick it by mistake. I reaccepted it so sorry

Answer (score 0):

If your prefix ranges followed the simple pattern of your first four (1-4) example id's, it would be a simple LIKE query using the first two characters of your prefix (range) beginning:

SELECT id FROM table WHERE prefix LIKE 'T6%';

But your fifth (5) example id has a prefix range that spans beyond the expected -7TZ range ending convention that the other four represented. If you have design control of the the prefix ranges then LIKE is another alternative.